# Haskell Strict MVar with Bang pattern

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

The following code example takes approx 2 seconds to execute. When the bang pattern in line 14 is removed however, it takes 60s. Can anyone explain what is going on?

I am using strict MVar so whatever is put into the MVar, should be fully evaluated to normal form. I would not expect a Bang pattern before inserting into the MVar to have any noticable effect.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import           Control.Concurrent.MVar.Strict
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           Data.Text.Encoding

main :: IO ()
main = do
    mvar <- newMVar T.empty

    let bsArr = map (\i -> encodeUtf8 $ T.pack $ "some strange string " ++ show i) [0 .. 30000 :: Int]
        mvarWriter =
            \lbs ->
                let !decoded = decodeUtf8 lbs
                in  modifyMVar_ mvar (\oldText -> return $ oldText <> decoded)

    mapM_ (\lbs -> mvarWriter lbs) bsArr
    print . T.length =<< readMVar mvar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```hs
  let !decoded = decodeUtf8 lbs
  oldText <- takeMVar mvar
  let !newText = oldText <> decoded
  putMVar mvar newText
```

Without bang pattern it is like this:

```hs
  oldText <- takeMVar mvar
  let !newText = oldText <> decodeUtf8 lbs
  putMVar mvar newText
```

Without bang pattern, the computation happens at the latest point possible. That is right before the new value is inserted. However, at that point the `MVar` is empty: the `oldText` has already been taken out. During this time no other threads can compute anything. So this means that only a single thread can do actual computation at any given time.

The bang pattern forces `decodeUtf8 lbs` to be evaluated before the `MVar` is taken. So that part of the computation can happen in parallel with other threads. Only the relatively cheap `oldText <> decoded` computation needs to happen in the critical section.